# How to use nested struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, nested

Hello i am new to C and i m having a problem with the nested struct. I m not gettign any errors nor warnings however it's not working. PLEASE HELP!
this is my code:

```
typedef struct stDonneesTagGroup1_packed
{
    U16 NombreGouttesRestantes; 
}__attribute__ ((packed)) stDonneesTagGroup1_packed;

typedef struct stDonneesTagGroup2_packed
{
    U8 NBBusesTotalesHS;
    U8 NBDefautBuseHS;
    U8 NBDefautConnectique;
    U8 NBConnectionTeteMMImpr;
    U8 NBOuvertureLevier;
}__attribute__ ((packed)) stDonneesTagGroup2_packed;

typedef struct stDonneesTagGroups
{
    stDonneesTagGroup1_packed *DonneesTagGroup1;
    stDonneesTagGroup2_packed *DonneesTagGroup2;
    stDonneesTagGroup3_packed *DonneesTagGroup3;
    stDonneesTagGroup4_packed *DonneesTagGroup4;
    stDonneesTagGroup5_packed *DonneesTagGroup5;
}__attribute__ ((packed)) stDonneesTagGroups;
```

main.c

```
{
    stDonneesTagGroups DonneesTagGroups;

    SetEnsembleDonneesGroups(&DonneesTagGroups);
}
```

SetEnsembleDonneesGroups

```
void SetEnsembleDonneesGroups(stDonneesTagGroups *DonneesTagGroups)
{
    DonneesTagGroups->DonneesTagGroup1->NombreGouttesRestantes = 3750;
    DonneesTagGroups->DonneesTagGroup2->NBBusesTotalesHS = 10;
    DonneesTagGroups->DonneesTagGroup2->NBConnectionTeteMMImpr = 15;
}
```

Comment: You need to define "not working" however I suspect it crashes. You will need to allocate the inner `struct`s before you start dereferencing their pointers.  Or, don't make them pointers at all...

Comment: You forgot to initialize `DonneesTagGroup1` etc., so you're trying to assign through undefined pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> How to use nested struct in C?

Your code doesn't have nested structs.

When you do:

```
typedef struct stDonneesTagGroups
{
    stDonneesTagGroup1_packed *DonneesTagGroup1;
    stDonneesTagGroup2_packed *DonneesTagGroup2;
    stDonneesTagGroup3_packed *DonneesTagGroup3;
    stDonneesTagGroup4_packed *DonneesTagGroup4;
    stDonneesTagGroup5_packed *DonneesTagGroup5;
}__attribute__ ((packed)) stDonneesTagGroups;
```

You have a struct with **5 pointers to other structs**. There is not any nested structs.

To get the structs nested remove the `*` like:

```
typedef struct stDonneesTagGroups
{
    stDonneesTagGroup1_packed *DonneesTagGroup1;
    stDonneesTagGroup2_packed *DonneesTagGroup2;
    stDonneesTagGroup3_packed *DonneesTagGroup3;
    stDonneesTagGroup4_packed *DonneesTagGroup4;
    stDonneesTagGroup5_packed *DonneesTagGroup5;
}__attribute__ ((packed)) stDonneesTagGroups;
```

and use it like:

```
void SetEnsembleDonneesGroups(stDonneesTagGroups *DonneesTagGroups)
{
    DonneesTagGroups->DonneesTagGroup1.NombreGouttesRestantes = 3750;
    ...
```

Comment: i did how you pointed me to do. but still it always doesn't work. the value gets back to 0 when it gets out of the function SetEnsembleDonneesGroups

Comment: @SabrineGuiga My code works - see https://ideone.com/YNhqtg Maybe you have another bug in some code you didn't post

Answer (score 0):

The struct type `stDonneesTagGroups` holds as members multiple pointers. These pointers must point to some valid memory area dedicated for the values you want to hold there.

This means that you must first allocate memory for the values that the members (`DonneesTagGroup1`, `DonneesTagGroup2`, ..., `DonneesTagGroup5`) point to.

You can do this either *statically, on stack, using local variables* that you then point the member pointers to or **dynamically, on heap, using the `malloc` function**.

I assume that you want to have an arbitrary number of such `stDonneesTagGroups` because you use pointers for the members. In this case, you cannot create local variables before runtime, so you'll want to allocate your memory dynamically, at runtime.

After finishing using a heap allocated memory area, you must "free" this area for further use by your program or other programs running on your operating system. You do this using the `free` function.

e.g.:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

[...]

int main() {

  stDonneesTagGroups DonneesTagGroups;
  // Allocate memory areas and make the members point to them.
  DonneesTagGroups.DonneesTagGroup1 = malloc(sizeof(stDonneesTagGroup1_packed));
  [...]
  DonneesTagGroups.DonneesTagGroup5 = malloc(sizeof(stDonneesTagGroup5_packed));

  SetEnsembleDonneesGroups(&DonneesTagGroups);

  // Free the memory allocated on heap.
  free(DonneesTagGroups.DonneesTagGroup1);
  [...]
  free(DonneesTagGroups.DonneesTagGroup5);

  return 0;
}
```

You can read more about dynamic memory allocation [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation).